# Multiple false stopovers cause directions search to fail

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm running a query twice on a set of Lat/Lng coords and getting failed results when there is more than one stopover.

- When stopover:false is set on a single waypoint, the search returns correctly
- When stopover:false is set on more than one waypoint, the search comes back with ZERO_RESULTS.
- When stopover:true is set on any number of waypoints, the waypoints appear to be dismissed from the directions distance.

  ```
  // Query 1 uses the format: Pickup - Taxi rank coods - Destination:
  query = 'from: 50.899083,0.040018 to: 50.875629,0.017858 to: 50.972639,0.016789';


  // Query 2 uses the format: Pickup - Waypoint 1 - Waypoint 2 - Destination
  query = 'from: 50.899083,0.040018 to: 50.82988,-0.14095 to: 50.87077,0.01328 to: 50.972639,0.016789';


  var start = query.split('from: '),
      end = start[1].split(' to: '),
      jLength = end.length,
      routeDistance = [],
      jWaypoints = [],
      request,
      i;

  start = end[0];
  // At this point, start = 50.899083,0.040018

  if( (jLength - 2) > 0 ) {
      for (i = jLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if( i != ( jLength - 1 ) && i != 0 ) {
              jWaypoints.push( {
                  location: end[i],
                  stopover: false
              });
          }
      }
  }
  end = end[jLength - 1];

  // end = 50.972639,0.016789
  // jWaypoints = [Object { location="50.87077,0.01328", stopover=false}, Object { location="50.82988,-0.14095", stopover=false}];


  if( jWaypoints.length >= 1 ) {
      request = {
          origin:start,
          destination:end,
          waypoints: jWaypoints,
          optimizeWaypoints: false,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };
  } else {
      request = {
          origin:start,
          destination:end,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };
  }


  directions.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          routeDistance.push(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value, response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value);
          passDistance(callback, stopnames, latlons, queries, queryindex, results, routeDistance);
      } else {
          console.log( status );
      }
  });

  // Query 1 comes out as: [20560, 1472] -> Correct
  // Query 2 comes out as: ZERO_RESULTS
  ```

/ - Edit - /

It transpires that when stopover is set to true, only the final waypoint is picked up. Still none the wiser about that.

Comment: Multiple waypoints with both stopover true and false work for me.  Perhaps you can make a fiddle that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks for testing it. Try this: [http://jsfiddle.net/2z45a/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/2z45a/3/). In the loaded query, the second waypoint is close to the end destination. In the commented out query, the second waypoint is a long way away. It doesn't seem to pick up the first waypoint in either example.

Comment: start, end and waypoints are not LatLng objects; waypoints are off the  road, that can be seen if markers are set at waypoint.

Comment: Not sure what I am looking for.  What do the alerts tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the final round up of distances before alerting them. By looping through all of the legs and summing the results, the correct distance is returned. From this:

```
 routeDistance.push(response.routes[0].legs[0])
```

to:

```
jDistance = 0;

for(i = 0, i >= response.routes[0].legs.length, i++) {
    jDistance += response.routes[0].legs[i];
}

routeDistance.push(jDistance);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use coordinates for a waypoint, it needs to be a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) object, not a string containing two numbers separated by a comma.

Comment: Having updated the waypoints and start/end strings to google.maps.LatLng objects, the same issue is occurring.When the query is Start -> Near Waypoint -> Far Waypoint -> Destination, the end alert (taken from the directions.route calculation) on line 69 returns 18863 mtrs. When the query is Start -> Far Waypoint -> Near Waypoint -> Destination, the alert returns 3449 metres. I'm a bit stumped as to why the same coords in different orders is returning such wildly different results. [http://jsfiddle.net/2z45a/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/2z45a/9/)

Comment: Looking at the coords, I don't think it's possible for the journey to be that much shorter on the Start-Far-Near-End query without missing out the Far waypoint altogether.

Comment: They [look fairly different](http://jsfiddle.net/2z45a/10/embedded/result/) to me

Comment: Sorry @geocodezip, I wasn't at all clear with my original question - my apologies. [This - http://jsfiddle.net/2z45a/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/2z45a/12/) should be a little clearer. To get my different results I was swapping the commented query out at the top of the function. I've now made it the second element in the query array. The query variable now holds two strings, one that goes S->Far->Near->D, and the second that goes S->Near->Far->D. The different results I was mentioning is still occurring as seen on the alerts

Comment: @trysmudford fyi: I manage to get working example with `stopover: false` changing query to `query = 'from: 50.899083,0.040018 to: 50.87177,0.01321 to: 50.830195,-0.14045 to: 50.972639,0.016789';`. It is changed just a little so that latlng are on the road and not off the road.

Comment: @AntoJurković Thanks for the suggestion but i'm not sure that it's going to be possible to go through the dataset to snap the latlng's to a road. Is there any way you know of that lets you use latlng's as waypoints regardless of the position?

Comment: @geocodezip is there any chance you could cast an eye over [http://jsfiddle.net/2z45a/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/2z45a/12/). Really struggling to find a fix. Thanks